# Ошибка при занесении данных в бд

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

При старте (`/start`) в таблице `groups` - должна создаваться строка с данными беседы в которой она прописана(должна вставлять только айди группы).

Если прописать её когда данных в базе с таким же айдишником группы нету, то все будет успешно - ошибок не будет, если же прописать её когда данные есть - будут ошибки и закроется соединение с базой данных. Попробовал написать проверку - не получись, как это можно решить и какую проверку лучше подскажете использовать?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    grouptype = message.chat.id
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    if grouptype < 0 and developer_id == user_id:
        group_id_ndb = message.chat.id

        conn = sqlite3.connect('dba.db', check_same_thread=False)
        cur = conn.cursor()

        group_idd = message.chat.id

        cur.execute('SELECT groupid FROM groups WHERE groupid = ("%s")' % group_idd)
        groups = cur.fetchall()
        if cur.fetchone() is None:
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO groups (groupid) VALUES ("%s")' % group_id_ndb)
            conn.commit()
            bot.send_message(group_id_ndb, 'Запись создана')
        else:
            bot.send_message(group_id_ndb, 'Запись не создана')

        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cur.execute('INSERT INTO groups (groupid) VALUES ("%s")' % group_id_ndb)` - что такое `(groupid)`? Это не нужно... Если не помогло, напишите ошибку...

Comment: Решил проблему, оказалось что неправильно была написана проверка, почему то до этого работало без проблем в других проектах